# Wordpress doesn't create table on plugin activation

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql

I am trying to create a table on the Wordpress database as the plugin gets activated. My code is the following:

in the main plugin file:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sillyplugin_install');
```

in the `activation.php` file:

```
function sillyplugin_install()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sillyplugindata';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$table_name'" ) != $table_name )
    {
            $sql = "create table $table_name (" . 
            "post_id bigint(20) unsigned not null," .
            "comment_id bigint(20) unsigned not null," .
            "silly_number int unsigned not null," .
            "primary key(post_id, silly_number)," .
            "foreign key(post_id) references wp_posts(ID) on delete cascade," .
            "foreign key(comment_id) references wp_comments(comment_ID) on delete cascade" . 
        ") $charset_collate;";

        add_option( 'sillyplugindata_version', '1.0');

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what goes wrong because everything seems to go fine except the table doesn't get created. All I managed to know is:

- the `register_activation_hook()` works properly and the callback function gets called;
- if the table does not exist the function executes what's in the `if` statement as it should;
- if I print the content of the `$sql` variable and try to execute the query manually on the MySQL client it works fine and it actually creates the table;
- if I try to print the return value of `dbDelta()` I get returned an empty array
- no error messages in the admin panel or debug/error log.

I am at loss here, why doesn't the table gets created?

Comment: dbDelta is extremely particular, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77287/4771) for a few hints. One issue that I see immediately is capitalization.

Comment: @Milo thank you for your suggestion, capitalizing the SQL code does not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: oh, I don't think it supports foreign key, you'll have to alter the table after creation.

Comment: @Milo that was it!! But if foreign keys are not supported how come the sql works perfectly fine on the database when executed on the mysql client and dbDelta is so fussy?

Comment: Create your foreign key after using dbDelta with $wpdb->query
This article can help you, I think http://www.browserstudios.com/2013/08/23/how-to-solve-the-problem-with-dbdelta-and-foreign-key/